# Put a sentence on 3 lines PHP

Tags: php

I have a sentence, this one can have as many words as possible. This sentence, I have to cut it on three lines maximum.

For example: 
"I am spiderman"

```
Array
(
[0] => I
1] => am
[2] => spiderman
)
```

"I love dogs and cats."

```
Array
(
[0] => I love
[1] => dogs and
[2] => cats
)
```

This is my code :

```
<?php
$string = "I like big apple";
$words = explode(' ', $string);

$maxLines = 3;
$nbWords = count($words);
$wordsByLines = ceil($nbWords/$maxLines);

if($wordsByLines == 0) {
    $wordsByLines = 1;
}

$index = 0;
$result = [];

for($i = 1; $i <= $nbWords; $i++) {
    $result[$index] .= $words[$i-1]." ";
    if($i % $wordsByLines == 0) {
        $result[$index+1] .= $words[$i-1]." ";
    }
}

print_r($result);
```

Result:

```
Array
(
    [0] => I like big apple 
    [1] => like apple 
)
```

Where's the mistake? I succeeded yesterday... but I didn't save the file. I couldn't find the solution

I'm getting the words out of my sentence. ( Explode ) 
I count my words ( count($words) )
I calculate the number of words to have by lines ( $wordsByLines = ceil($nbWords/$maxLines); )
I make a modulo to put the word on the corresponding line

Ty

Comment: If you enable error reporting, you will get various undefined index errors, using `$result[$index] .=` when the index isn't set will generate a message.  Also what would you expect from `"I like big apple"` split into 3 rows?

Comment: `$index` is not increasing.

Comment: $index increases in if ($index+1); 
Yes I want in three rows ... with the current method, a sentence of 4 words would be on 2 lines 4/3 = 1.333 but rounded to 2 so 2 words per line. Good at the limit it does not matter, but ideally yes.

Comment: Yes $index[0] not exists because $index is an empty array, but it doesn't matter. It is created in the loop.

Comment: The array elements are created, but also so are a lot of `Notice: Undefined offset ...` messages.

Comment: Yeah, you're right. It's better to make empty columns in the table like the code just presented. I'll remember for next time :)

Answer (score 2):

```
// number or required lines
$chunksCount = 3;
$words = explode(' ', 'I love dogs and cats');
// count chunkSize and split array of words into chunks
$chunks = array_chunk($words, ceil(count($words) / $chunksCount)); 
$lines = [];
// Implode back
foreach ($chunks as $chunk) {
    $lines[] = implode(' ', $chunk);
}

echo implode('<br />', $lines);
```

Some edge cases you can process yourself.

Comment: Great, thanks to you. Your approach is interesting, I didn't know about array_chunk. I'm going to retain this function, it can be useful for the next few times.

Answer (score 0):

The loop you have is the main problem, not sure what you are attempting to do with it, so instead I've altered it to the following (some comments in code for changes)...

```
$string = "I like big apple";
$words = explode(' ', $string);

$maxLines = 3;
$nbWords = count($words);
$wordsByLines = ceil($nbWords/$maxLines);

// Initialise the lines to blank
$result = [ '', '', '' ];

// Start loop at 0, go to < rather then <=
for($i = 0; $i < $nbWords; $i++) {
    // Just find which line by using floor()
    $result[ floor($i / $wordsByLines) ] .= $words[$i]." ";
}

print_r($result);
```

Comment: Thanks for your code. It's a different logic, I hadn't thought of it that way. It's true that it's more understandable. 
For my loop, I make a modulo to know in which line to put the word. I succeeded like that yesterday

Comment: I think my code was like this (+/-): 
https://pastebin.com/rcmiAhz0

I don't know why I have zeros on $result[1] & $result[2] but yesterday it worked exactly like your code :)

Comment: You have `$result[$index] +=` = should be `.=`. Actually you don't need that line at all